# Why is identity element required for groups?

Tags: group-theory

I would like to know the necessity for having an identity element for every group.
I know the meaning of an identity element.

Comment: How would you make sense of the existence of inverses without it (yes, I know there are ways to do this, but they are not nearly as nice and one would like).

Comment: Why is it requiredto have a binary operation for groups?

Comment: Groups are defined as having an identity element. You might be interested in reading about [semigroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup) for the more general concept that doesn't require an identity element.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! I didn't downvote, but don't understand the conceptual origins of your question: The concept of (and the name for) a _group_ was introduced (or, if you prefer, _invented_) for mathematical convenience, so that a commonly-occurring collection of properties (including having an identity element) could be unambiguously referenced with one short word. Can you perhaps try to clarify where your uncertainty lies, or what type of answer you're seeking?

Comment: I suspect the question you really wanted to ask is slightly different from the one you asked.  There are many contexts in which groups arise.  In each one, there may be a reason why you want to look at a mathematical object where an identity element exists, rather than one where it doesn't (which wouldn't be a group, but would be something else).  What context are you interested in?

Comment: I think we should encourage questions like this, which ask for reasons and motivations of concepts.

Comment: The identity element is required for groups because the definition of a group requires an identity element.  What you probably mean is why does the definition of a group have having an identity as one of its properties?  There is such a thing that has the same properties as a group but without identity/inverses - it's called a semi-group.  So there you go, one can define objects like groups but without identities, it's already been done.  But if we only define semi-groups and never define groups, then there's a whole lot of math we cannot develop.

Answer (score 3):

Most definitions of general objects in mathematics are a consequence of abstracting the properties of certain key examples that the object was originally developed to study so it could be extended to use in other fields. For example, the theory of measure and integration developed from precursor theories that were generalizations of ideas that ultimately had their roots in area and volume formulas that arose in construction problems in Ancient Greece.

Groups originally arose in the study of the symmetry properties of geometric objects under the classical isometry and similarity transformations of Euclidean geometry. It was Felix Klein who recognized that the set of isometries in Euclidean space-rotation,reflection and identity-formed a group under composition of functions since the operation is associative,yields a unique identity function and an inverse for each mapping which yields the identity map when composed with the mapping. For example, a reflection of an object through a mirror plane is it's own inverse since applying the map twice successively leaves the object unchanged and is therefore the identity mapping.

[image]

The generalization of the group of transformations of necessity gave an identity element in the definition of group when Leopold Kronecker proposed the abstract definition at the end of the 19th century.

Comment: Along these lines, another important point is that the identity map is "obviously" a symmetry of the given object. Who said that a symmetry has to actually move anything?

Comment: @LeeMosher The identity is trivially a symmetry since it's an isometry of the plane. (For the OP: Ask yourself why.)

Answer (score -1):

By requiring having a unit $e\in G$ you achieve to things:

1. Avoiding dealing with the concept of empty sets as the base of the Group.
2. Avoiding dealing with empty operations (as an operation is a subset of $(G\times G)\times G)$.

Since the empty set and empty operation have all the other axioms of groups there could be an empty Group. The empty group will be contradicting almost every theorem.

Also, requiring a unit element gives a meaning to having an inverse element and to solving equations.

From the comments below I have missed one main thing. A Group is a structure that exists in nature a lot.

Comment: I think there is some merit to your answer, but it definitely could be formulated better.

Comment: @CameronWilliams and after I re formulated it?

Comment: Much better! $\,\,$

Comment: This looks like a circular reasoning to me. We require a unit to exclude empty group, in which most theorems do not apply; but the theorems do not apply because they rely heavily on the unit.

Also, inverses can be formulated without identity: $x^{-1}$ is such that $\forall y:\, x^{-1}xy=y$. And "solving equations" can be done without literally anything.

Comment: @lisyarus so why do we use the existence of a unit on a Group? if not to avoid "correct by meaningless" situations and giving tools such as solving equations? You all criticize and downvote but I see no other answers.

Comment: @JonesY Unfortunatelly, I don't have time to give a full, thoughtful answer right now, but I'd say that because 1) Such structures arise naturally, usually as groups of automorphisms 2) This is just a definition, we have semigroups without units or quasigroups with division but still without units.